# Kubernetes: Start webserver from yaml pod definition file

Tags: kubernetes

I have a YAML file for pod definition. Wanted to start the application using a start script. When I bash into pod application is not started. That means the start script is not executed. When the YAML file is executed, I want it to execute the script file to start the webserver. So that when I bash into the pod, my application web server is running. Actually my application is such that when I install rpm, it automatically creates start script in home/ folder. So when I bash into container, im in / dir. I just need to go to /home and execute start script. A portion from YAML file below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-pod6
  labels:
    name: app-pod
    app: containerization
spec:
  containers:
  - name: appimage1
    image: appimage6:1.0
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "cd home/ && ./start.sh"]
    ports:
     - containerPort: 8000
```

Dockerfile of appimage

```
FROM amazoncorretto:8
WORKDIR /
ADD app.rpm .
ADD start.sh .
RUN rpm -ivh app.rpm && bash
RUN chmod +x start.sh
EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: What purpose does the `command` instruction serve in your case? why do you need to tail /dev/null?

Comment: @jabbson.. I wanted the pod to not exit so that I can bash into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run the **shell** script in the **argument** of **YAML** config

you should be using the multiple command-line options something similar to

```
command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >
            i=0;
            while [ $i -lt 100 ];
            do
             echo "hello $i";
             echo "$i :  $(date)" >> /var/mylog/1.log;
             echo "$(date)" >> /var/mylog/2.log;
             i=$((i+1));
             sleep 1;
            done
```

if you want to run he multiple commands you could try.

This way you are opening bash as you mentioned and running the shell script.

```
command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >
            ./start.sh;
            tail -f /dev/null
```

another example

```
containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
      echo "running below scripts"
      echo "command 2"
```

**Update**

Example running shell script

Use this in Kubernetes

```
containers:
        - image: busybox
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "cd home/ &&  ./test.sh && mkdir new/ && other commands"]
          name: busybox
```

Comment: @Harsh...Ive updated the yaml file in question. Pod status is crashloopbackoff. It is successful only when I add 'tail -f /dev/null'. But still it dosent go to home/ dir and execute the script.

Comment: you are not at all adding the shell script into the docker file will it be still exist there?

Comment: you need to add your shell script first to docker image also, try to rebuild again by adding the file.

Comment: ive already done that in dockerfile. Just didnt post the entire dockerfile due to privacy concern. Though, Ive updated the dockerfile. The problem seems to be in yaml command and args cmds. Atleast it should change the dir to /home. Then we just need to execute the start script

Comment: you are adding your file at `/` in YAML you will be using the `/home` so it wont work as your file is at `/`

Comment: Actually my application is such that when I install rpm, it automatically creates start script in home/ folder. So when I bash into container, im in / dir. I just need to go to /home and execute start script. So i dont need to manually place start script inside container

Comment: i would recommend trying to debug or running command like `ls` to check fix exist at place or not. Or starting the container in exec mode and check file exist or not